# Using trellis as a framework for managing UI interaction rules

Tags: python, user-interface

Does anyone have experience with [trellis](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Trellis)?  Looking at it as a framework for defining rules for field interaction and validation in grids and data entry screens.

Comment: Did you learn any more since asking the question? You may want to provide an answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this project has died. No new stuff to the page has been added to it since your question. Also I think that new language features in Python 2.6 and Python 3 are removing the need of some of the offered constructs.

Comment: Which new language features are those? I couldn't find one that seemed related.